# Angular UI frameworks like Angular Materials, PrimeNG etc.. Not Working for my application

Tags: angular

I am developing the angular application in the angular 13 version in that I installed some packages, Installed properly I think so but whenever I am running that application I was getting too many errors like( Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' required 6 type argument(s).) could you please solve....

I am trying to solve that problem I didn't find anything on google.
whenever I write import code in app.modules.ts file is not showing error but whenever I run the code its showing too many errors, I don't know why those frameworks are not working

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Is there some way you can paste, via the Snippet Editor, which is opened with the "<>" icon above the text box, enough of your code to reproduce the error? That way people might be able to suggest solutions. Otherwise there is very little to go on, to even understand what your problem is. Keep the code short please: just enough to reproduce the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I too had so many errors while I started working with angular material. Try updating these packages.
for example:
npm install --save @angular/material@14.2.0
It may work the same for other packages. so, try same for other packages with your desired version.

```
"@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/cdk": "~14.2.0",
"@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/material": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
```

Comment: Not working I try to install that again I was getting same errors